# How to communicate between a WebView and ChromeTab?

Tags: javascript, php, android, android-webview

I have an app that is a webview and should end on a ChromeTab. 
I read that it's impossible to pass a cookie or keep the session.

Checking for solutions.

1. Ideal: Read a local file. Is it possible to read local files with javaScript but using paths (without inputs, ie without user interaction)?
2. Maybe I could get the sid in the webview with php, pass it by GET to ChromeTab and from there load it? (I need to check if it is functional)

Comment: Try using time dependent tokens and database storage...